# Why does div content jump after slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  <style>
  #toggle {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: crimson;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="clickme">Click moi</button>
<div id="toggle">
  <p>This will slide in and out.</p>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').click(function () {
    $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "slide" );
  });
});
</script>
```

The height of the #toggle div should be constant before/during/after the slide effect. For some reason the div slides out and then the height increases to 50px. I wanted to know why this is happens.

Comment: A fiddle would be great :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jabupacu/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Removed `p` as it wasn't required for this example. It's works, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3bVZy/

If you require `p`, let me know.

**EDIT**
For the same distance, in this example, add the following to your `#toggle` CSS:

```
  position: relative;
  top:15px;
```

Comment: The p is required because eventually the div will hold content and I want the content to slide "in place" with the div.

Comment: Updated my answer with CSS for positioning. You probably want to use `span` instead of `p`.

Comment: @Elton See comment above, how about this kind of thing: http://jsfiddle.net/x5myx/

Answer (score 1):

the problem is Paragraphe margin ,
if you set paragraphe `P` margin to 0 , 
it will work perfectly

```
  p { margin: 0; }
```

That's will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').click(function () {         
    $("#toggle" ).toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

I have changed the jquery reference and also the css part

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/d6J7y/6/)

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/3bVZy/1/)